# Как записать в файл (блокнот) через переменную типа структура?

Tags: c++, c

Здравствуйте такой вопрос как записать в файл (блокнот) мою таблицу через одну переменную типа структура, у меня получилось сделать только через массив структур, а надо через переменную типа структура.

вот моя структура:

```
struct prog {
string name;
unsigned int kol;
double time1;
double time2;
}lab[10];
```

а вот как я создавал таблицу и записывал в файл(блокнот)

```
FILE* f;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cout << i + 1 << ": ";
    cout << "Введите: название программы, количество строк кода, Время исп. на SGI Callenge (cек), 
 Время исп. на SGI Indy (cек) >\n";
    cin >> lab[i].name;
    if (!strcmp(lab[i].name.c_str(), "***")) {
        *n = i;
        break;
    }

    cin >> lab[i].kol;
    cin >> lab[i].time1;
    cin >> lab[i].time2;


}

fopen_s(&f, "numbers.txt", "w");
fprintf(f, "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
----------------\n");
fprintf(f, "|Время выполнения некоторых программ, которые применяют параллельные алгоритмы                          
|\n");
fprintf(f, "|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
---------------|\n");
fprintf(f, "|Название программы|Количество строк ввода|Время исп. на SGI Callenge (cек)|Время исп. на 
SGI Indy (cек)|\n");
fprintf(f, "|------------------|----------------------|--------------------------------|------------- 
---------------|\n");


for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {

    fprintf(f, "|%-18s|%-22u|%-32.2lf|%-28.2lf|\n", lab[i].name.c_str(), lab[i].kol, lab[i].time1, 
lab[i].time2);
    fprintf(f, "|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
-------------------|\n");
}
fclose(f);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что я непонятно ответил вам в комментарии к передыдущему вопросу?...

```
struct prog {
    string name;
    unsigned int kol;
    double time1;
    double time2;
} lab;

fopen_s(&f, "numbers.txt", "w");
fprintf(f, "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
fprintf(f, "|Время выполнения некоторых программ, которые применяют параллельные алгоритмы                          |\n");
fprintf(f, "|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n");
fprintf(f, "|Название программы|Количество строк ввода|Время исп. на SGI Callenge (cек)|Время исп. на SGI Indy (cек)|\n");
fprintf(f, "|------------------|----------------------|--------------------------------|----------------------------|\n");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << i + 1 << ": ";
    cout << "Введите: название программы, количество строк кода, Время исп. на SGI Callenge (cек),  Время исп. на SGI Indy (cек) >\n";
    cin >> lab.name;
    if (!strcmp(lab.name.c_str(), "***"))
    {
        *n = i;
        break;
    }

    cin >> lab.kol;
    cin >> lab.time1;
    cin >> lab.time2;

    fprintf(f, "|%-18s|%-22u|%-32.2lf|%-28.2lf|\n", lab.name.c_str(), lab.kol, lab.time1, lab.time2);
}


fprintf(f, "|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n");
fclose(f);
```

Comment: а как быть в том случае если нужно мою структуру заполнить рандомно? Я вот так попробовал for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
 {
  a.name = "StName" + to_string(rand() % 10 + 1);
  a.kol = rand() % 7589 + 486;
  a.time1 = (rand() % 600 + 1) / 10.0;
  a.time2 = (rand() % 600 + 1) / 10.0;
 }   но оно выводит одно и тоже r раз.

Comment: Вы точно не вызываете каждый раз `srand()`? Это первое предположение. Второе - вы просто не так используете `a`. Или у вас "каждый раз" - при каждом запуске программы? Ведь попробуй пойми, что вы имеете в виду...

Comment: srand написан я имею ввиду что сгенерировалась первая строка и она повторяется до конца таблицы  мне кажется что без а[i] здесь не обойтись.

Comment: все заработало просто рандомизацию и вывод поставил в один цикл

Comment: Значит, вы неверно использовали `srand`.